# How do I import not whole Configuration class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "package1"
})
class Config1 {

    @Bean
    public Class3 class3() {
        return new Class3();
    }

    static class Class3 {
    }
}

package package1;
class Class1 {
}

package package1;
class Class2 {
}
```

So, `Config1` has `Class1`, `Class2` and `Class3`

I have the next config class as well

```
@Configuration
@Import(Config1.class)
class Config2 {

    @Bean
    public SomeClass someClass(Class1 class1, Class3 class3) {
        return new SomeClass(class1, class3);
    }
}
```

And here's a problem. `Config2` needs only `class1` and `class3` beans from `Config1`. It's impossible to import them with `Class2` cause it has a lot of dependencies. So, my question is how do i solve it ?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is, please elaborate. Btw, where is the bean of Class1 created?

Comment: @msfoster i'd like to import class1 and class3 but not class2

Comment: I still dont understand. What do u mean by "import"? Please provide actual and expected outcome.

Comment: @msfoster i mean when you wirte @Import(Config1.class) you have configured by Config1 class beans

Comment: You are importing a configuration, where is the Class2 bean?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please provide a complete example of your problem.
With that being said you should probably split Config1 if you don't want to register all the beans.

Comment: Is class1 a bean or ? Because you are trying to autowire it in Config2 someClass method